# C++; How to use a Global token within a namespace

Tags: c++, macros, enums, namespaces

I am extending an existing component which defines global TRUE and FALSE tokens. My extension is defining, within a new namespace 'new_namespace' an enum 'new_enum' which has values TRUE and FALSE. The compiler is failing to compile this because of a namespace collision.

```
#define FALSE (0)
#define TRUE (1)

namespace new_namespace {
  class new_class {
  public :
  enum new_enum {
    TRUE = (0),
    FALSE = (1)
  };
  };
}
```

I would have hoped this would have been supported ... am I missing something.

Best Regards

Comment: After macro substitution, your `enum` is now: `enum new_enum { (1) = (0), (0) = (1) };`

Comment: Also, the fact that you put parentheses around the values in the `enum` makes me think you think that `enum`s are like macros. You definitely don't need parentheses there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Macros are handled by the preprocessor, which (as the name implies) runs before the compiler proper. What it does is *replace* the macro "call" with the text in the macro body. So what your `enum` looks like after the preprocessor step, and what the actual compiler sees, is:

```
enum new_enum {
    (1) = (0),
    (0) = (1)
};
```

This is not legal C++, and the reason the compiler complains.

Answer (score 0):

Joachim has identified your problem correctly so I won't repeat the answer. But I want to comment on how to solve it. There is really no reason to have those tokens as defines, I would strongly advocate replacing them like this:

```
const bool TRUE = true;
const bool FALSE = false;
```

It's just possible that this will result in type problems, although it's most likely that they will gracefully by implicitly cast. If you do see typing problems, try this instead:

```
const int TRUE = 1;
const int FALSE = 0;
```

Either way these constants will obey the normal scoping rules and no longer conflict.